# Error: "We are unable to issue token from this api version for a micro acc."

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, oauth, onedrive

I'm writing the javascript code to save file in onedrive helping with https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v6/js-picker-save.htm

For the same,I am using my personal account *@live.com and had added the application in microsoft and pass the app_id as client id in javascript tag.

But faced that issue to get the token and open the one drive exprorer.

> We are unable to issue tokens from this api version for a Microsoft account. Please contact the application vendor as they need to use version 2.0 of the protocol to support this.

[image: Error]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.live.net/v6.0/OneDrive.js" id="onedrive-js" client-id="78ef3a97-45fe-416c-a8ed-b618caee43c9"></script>
    <div>
    <div class="pickerDemo hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
        <div class="row">
            <span class="cell heading">File</span><span class="cell">

                <input id="inputFile" name="inputFile" type="file">
            </span>
        </div><div class="row">
            <span class="cell heading">File name</span><span class="cell">
                <input id="fileName" type="text" name="fileName">
                <label>Default: the file's local name</label>
            </span>
        </div><div class="row">
            <span class="cell heading">Button</span><span class="cell">
                <button onclick="javascript:launchOneDriveSaver();" title="Save to OneDrive">
                    <img src="https://js.live.net/v5.0/images/SkyDrivePicker/SkyDriveIcon_white.png" style="vertical-align: middle; height: 16px;">
                    <span class="oneDriveButton">Save to OneDrive</span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div><div>&nbsp;</div><div class="row">
            <span class="cell heading" style="vertical-align: top;">Result</span><span class="cell">
                <div id="saverConsole" class="console">Save a file to OneDrive to see the return result</div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function launchOneDriveSaver(){
      var saveOptions = {
          file: "inputFile", /* The id of a file type input element or a valid data URI string */
          fileName: "file.txt", /* Required if `saverOptions.file` is a data URI string */
          openInNewWindow: true,
          success: function () { /* upload is complete */ },
          progress: function (p) { /* upload is progressing */ },
          cancel: function () { /* upload was cancelled */ },
          error: function (e) { /* an error occurred */ }
      }
      OneDrive.save(saveOptions);
  }


</script>
```

Comment: It'd be easier for the readers if you could add your code to the question.

Comment: I think this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43365494/88122

Comment: Doesn't find the option to change web site target v1.0 to v2.0